# CSS Flexbox no funciona en Safari

Tags: css, css3, flexbox, safari

Me funciona perfecto en Chrome, Firefox y Explorer, pero en Safari (5.1.7) no.
Adjunto capturas de pantalla.

Las **imagenes 1 y 2** es **como deberia verse** (así se ve en Chrome, Firefox y Explorer.)

La **imagen 3** es como se ve en **SAFARI**. La **"section-intro" no se muestra a todo el alto de la pantalla,** y las **4 cajas de texto no se muestran correctamente**

**En la imagen 4 se ve que en el inspector de Safari, salen esos 'warnings' en el CSS.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo entendido que hay un «bug» en Safari para iOS el cual no toma correctamente las unidades viewport; pero dudo que esto suceda para macOS. Por la imagen que has puesto, dicha versión de Safari **no reconoce** `vh` como unidad de medida para la propiedad `height`; ni siquiera reconoce flexbox en su totalidad. Asumo que es una versión muy antigua.

Comment: La 5.1... va por la 12, y si es en Windows se descontinuó justo después de esa versión. No me preocuparía. Si necesitas testar para iOS/MacOS entonces actualiza tu Safari a una versión más reciente. Puedes usar Google Analytics para averiguar qué versiones de Safari usan tus usuarios.

Comment: Se puede observar en [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex) que las versiones `3.1` a `6` de **Safari** no es compatible, de la versión `6.1` a `8` el soporte es parcial. Es decir, que podrías utilizarlo de la forma `display: -webkit-flex` y a partir de versión 9 es totalmente compatible. Ten en cuenta que el porcentaje de uso de esas versiones no compatibles juntas apenas llega al `0.35%`. Como dice @DanielAbril, no hay que preocuparse por ello.

Answer (score 1):

Si entras a la página https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox puedes ver la compatibilidad de los componentes o atributos que usas en cada uno de los diferentes navegadores. Como se puede ver si entras en la página flexbox es compatible con todos esos (salen en verde).Puede ser por la versión de Safari que estás utilizando que sea muy anterior. Si no conocías la página échale un vistazo.